# macbook pro 2017 battery drains even in charge

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, touch-bar

I have the strangest problem ever my mac drains even if it's charging. I have attached a picture to let you understand: as you can see the battery level decreases even if it is plugged in. I am not doing anything special than what I used to do with my previous mid 2014 mac but still this machine is not able to cope with it. It's a disaster. Any help appreciated.[image]

**Edit**

as @Buscar suggested I reviewed my battery info from the menu here is the result:

[image]

So the battery number I so it positive but it seems it's not recovering but slowly decreasing...

Comment: What are the specs on your charger?  If the charger is not the original it may not charge your computer fast enough to keep up with use.

Comment: you could try a bigger charger. By bigger I mean more Watts.

Comment: But confirm its suitable for your computer..

Answer (score 3):

If your MacBook Pro is discharging while in use and plugged in, you are probably using the wrong charger.  The 2017 MacBook Pro uses either a 61W or 87W charger.  See:  [Find the right power adapter and cable for your Mac notebook](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)

When selecting a charger, always go equal or bigger than what you need.  The wattage rating is the maximum that will will supply, not "push".  In other words, if your device needs less, it won't harm it.  However, if it needs more, there won't be any more to give.

Answer (score 2):

Your post only shows Power Consumption, nothing about charging.

It looks normal.

To actually see the Charging versus consumption go to

Apple (top left) >> About this Mac >> System Report >> Power

without Charger it looks like this

It is a Negative number, saying the battery is been drained.

[image]

With Charge, it is a positive Number, means Battery is been Charged.

[image]

However, if it remains Negative you have a problem with Charger or MagSafe adapter or even the Battery it self.

Comment: thanks. Since I restarted the laptop , as usual for a couple of hours I don't see the problem. I will post in the next days.